# Новая строчка начинается без отступов

Tags: html, css

```css
.dish_description {
  margin-top: 24px;
  width: 400px;
}

.dish_description a {
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="dish_description">
  <a href="#">If you're looking for decadence, look no further — you've found the Holy Grail of desserts. Honestly, this cake makes us wonder why Bananas Foster hasn't always been served on top of ice cream cake.</a>
</div>
```

Скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не помешало бы и `html` добавить

Comment: HTML

<div class="dish_description">
            <a>
                If you're looking for decadence, look no further — you've found the Holy Grail of desserts. Honestly, this cake makes us wonder why Bananas Foster hasn't always been served on top of ice cream cake.
            </a>
        </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы добавляете внутренний отступ `inline` элементу (ссылка по умолчанию `display: inline`).

Чтобы отступ сработал, нужно чтобы ссылка была блочным элементом (или отступ задавать родительскому `div` элементу `.dish_description`, который по умолчанию `display: block`):

```css
.dish_description {
  margin-top: 24px;
  width: 400px;
}

.dish_description a {
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dish_description">
  <a href="#">If you're looking for decadence, look no further — you've found the Holy Grail of desserts. Honestly, this cake makes us wonder why Bananas Foster hasn't always been served on top of ice cream cake.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Как Вы радикально сразу - из `inline` в `block` :) А как же `inline-block` ?

Comment: @UModeL, параграф ```display: block``` и тут ссылка как параграф, поэтому так радикально в данном случае